# Accessing JSP website running on localhost in host desktop from client Laptop

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

Hello friends please help, I have developed a JSP based Shopping Website on Netbeans and uses APACHE TOMCAT SERVER to run it on localhost . I want to ask whether its possible to access this localhost website from another laptop/ desktop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help 
[Access Tomcat Via LAN](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJV3AotyAaw&list=UUDphhvsh-ZmiEPOZs-LHnjA&feature=c4-overview)